# Compare objects to set selected value in pre-loaded combobox silverlight MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm trying to set seletected value to a pre-loaded combobox using silverlight with MVVM.

I load these combobox items before selecting value.

For example I have a combobox to select a country. My first step is to load a List which is bound to the combobox source. This is loading perfectly.

After this, I have a "SelectedCountry" object bound to the selectedItem of the combobox in a two-way binding.

This is working perfect when I select any of the combobox values and my SelectedCountry object is correctly selected.

The problem comes when I try to assign the selected value in my ViewModel. This way, the combobox selecteditem is not updated.

I suppose this is because, on fact, they are not the same object (they have the same values but they are diferent references).

Should this work if I re-implement the equals method? Or should I find the same object by searching into the List?? This would be very easy because this two countries would be the same if they have the same id... but I can have more complex objects and I think the equals method would be better.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit for adding some code example:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="7" Margin="6,0" Name="cBTipoPoliza" VerticalAlignment="Center" TabIndex="4" ItemsSource="{Binding TiposPolizas, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding TipoPoliza,  Mode=TwoWay}">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding nombre_tipo}" />
       </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I just override the .Equals() method to check if they are equal by ID or Name

Comment: This also implies overriding HashCode and operator = as well. While you're at it override operator !=

Comment: I've tried this but nothing changes... are you sure the equals method is evaluated when I assign my "selectedValue" object?

Comment: I have added the ComboBox code. I think I'm doing it the way you say.

Comment: The object I'm using is a Service provided one so I'll try to make a local copy to set a breakpoint in my client-side object. Thanks for all your help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid having multiple copies of the same object in memory at the same time. One method to do this is to have your VM be the source of objects. When you load the list have the VM do it and expose an AvailableCountries ObservableCollection property on the VM that your ComboBox can bind to.

If your objects are semantically equal based on ID, definitely override Equals and == and != and hashcode. However be careful because if you're enabling people to update the objects you can run into collisions (even within the same instance of the app) where one screen is holding onto stale data.